# how to display msg for 2 seconds before window.location

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

JS:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
  }).done(id => {
    this._handleMsg('data saved.');
    const newUrl = dutils.urls.resolve( 'test', { test_id: id } );
    window.location.replace(newUrl);
  }).fail(( jqXHR, textStatus, errormsg ) => {
    this._handleError('Sorry. Report not saved. Reason:' + errormsg); // eslint-disable-line no-alert
  });



 _handleMsg(msg) {
    if (msg) {
      $('#header .form-group').addClass('has-msg');
      $('.report-error').html(msg).delay(200000).fadeIn(500000);
    } else {
      $('#header .form-group').removeClass('has-msg');
    }
  },
```

SCSS:

```
.report-error{
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}


.has-msg, .has-msg:focus, .has-msg:hover{
    input {
        border-color: #843534;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 6px #ce8483;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        outline: 0;
    }
    label, .report-error{
        visibility: visible;
        color: green;
        font-size:30px;
    }
}
```

I need to show the message "data saved." for 2 seconds and then redirect to another url. but it seems that **$('.report-error').html(msg).delay(200000).fadeIn(500000);** does not work.

Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
 203         this._handleMsg('data saved.');
 204         setTimeout(()=>{
 205           const newUrl = dutils.urls.resolve( 'test', { test_id: id } );
 206           window.location.replace(newUrl);
 207         }, 2000);
```

Comment: using setTimeout() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript's timeout.: `setTimeout()` ([look here for more infos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout))

Here is [a fiddle using setTimeout](https://jsfiddle.net/vcjbnh8b/1/) and calling a function with parameters.

The code itself is as follows:

```
function alertMessage(firstMessage, secondMessage) {
  alert(firstMessage + ' ' + secondMessage);
}

setTimeout(
  alertMessage, // name of the function to be called after the delay
  1000, // the size of the delay in ms
  'Hello world!', // the first parameter to be parsed to the called function
  'You rock!' // the second parameter to be parsed to the called function
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: setTimeout(this._handleMsg('Report saved.'), 6000);????It seems that it cannot last 6 seconds.

Comment: setTimeout(function() { handleMessage('Message saved'); }, 6000);

Comment: I'll write a fiddle when I'm off the road.

Comment: This will help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Thanks. but it is not useful to delay the alert display. I used setTimeout() to delay  window.location.replace(), which works now. see my update yesterday morning.

Comment: It's useful for whatever you need it for. The alert is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
  }).done(id => {
    this._handleMsg('data saved.');
    const newUrl = dutils.urls.resolve( 'test', { test_id: id } );
   //below function will call after 2s that solve your purpose
    setTimeout(function () { window.location.replace(newUrl); }, 2000);

  }).fail(( jqXHR, textStatus, errormsg ) => {
    this._handleError('Sorry. Report not saved. Reason:' + errormsg); // eslint-disable-line no-alert
  });
```